# Django add form data in two models

Tags: django, django-models

Im trying create a new book and review from on request.POST. The issue here is the issue is that the data needs to go to two models with foreign keys. Here is the request.POST:

```
def add(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    result = Review.objects.addBook_and_Review(
        user=request.session['id'],
        title=request.POST['title'],
        author=request.POST['author'],
        new_author=request.POST['new_author'],
        review=request.POST['review'],
        rating=request.POST['rating']
    )
    return redirect('add')
else:
    return render(request, 'books/add.html')
```

And here is the the custom manager and the two models (Review and Book). Note the Review model with foreign Keys.

```
class ReviewManager(models.Manager):

   def addBook_and_Review(self, **kwargs):
      #custom manager code here
      return True

class BookManager(models.Manager):
   print('hit book manager')
   pass

class User(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   alias = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   email = models.EmailField()
   pw_hash = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
   objects = UserManager()

class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
   objects = BookManager()

class Review(models.Model):
   review = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   rating = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   objects = ReviewManager()
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Apart from the fact that you don't validate your data; you should certainly be using a form to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy. If you want to create Book and Review objects using one POST request, do the following (continuing your code):

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        book = Book.objects.create(
            title=request.POST['title'],
            author=request.POST['author'],
        )

        result = Review.objects.addBook_and_Review(
            user=request.session['id'],
            title=request.POST['title'],
            author=request.POST['author'],
            new_author=request.POST['new_author'],
            review=request.POST['review'],
            rating=request.POST['rating'],
            book=review)
        return redirect('add')
    else:
        return render(request, 'books/add.html')
```

It is recommended that you do this after the validation using forms.